# JavaScript: insert image element at keyboard caret next to existing image element

Tags: javascript, dom

Using the following XHTML code...

```
<div contenteditable="true">
<img alt="" src="1.png" />
</div>
```

...if the user has the keyboard caret just after the image element (either anchorNode or focusNode) I want to use a W3C standard method such as appendChild or insertBefore to insert a new image element.

I've tried the following to determine the location in the DOM...

```
alert(
'focusNode = '+window.getSelection().focusNode
+'\n\npreviousSibling = '+window.getSelection().focusNode.previousSibling
+'\n\nnextSibling = '+window.getSelection().focusNode.nextSibling
+'\n\nparentNode = '+window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode);

try
{
alert(
'focusNode = '+window.getSelection().focusNode
+'\n\n.previousSibling.previousSibling = '+window.getSelection().focusNode.previousSibling.previousSibling
+'\n\n.nextSibling.nextSibling = '+window.getSelection().focusNode.nextSibling.nextSibling
+'\n\nparentNode = '+window.getSelection().focusNode.parentNode);
} catch (err) {}

alert(
'anchorNode = '+window.getSelection().anchorNode
+'\n\npreviousSibling = '+window.getSelection().anchorNode.previousSibling
+'\n\nnextSibling = '+window.getSelection().anchorNode.nextSibling
+'\n\nparentNode = '+window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode);

try
{
alert(
'anchorNode = '+window.getSelection().anchorNode
+'\n\n.previousSibling.previousSibling = '+window.getSelection().anchorNode.previousSibling.previousSibling
+'\n\n.nextSibling.nextSibling = '+window.getSelection().anchorNode.nextSibling.nextSibling
+'\n\nparentNode = '+window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode);
} catch (err) {}
```

I've also tried this which simply tells me how many whitespace characters (breaklines) there are...

```
alert(window.getSelection().anchorOffset+'\n\n'+window.getSelection().focusOffset);
```

I have not been able to determine how to find the image directly next to the keyboard caret.

---

My goal is to do this using W3C methods and properties only so....

1.) No use of proprietary Microsoft inner--- anything methods.

2.) No use of frameworks and not simply because they use inner--- anything methods.

3.) I'm trying to determine if an image element is right next to the caret, if it's text then that is a different condition (just mention {alert('in or next to text');}).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.setAttribute('alt','alternative text');
img.setAttribute('src','2.png');
window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).insertNode(img);
```